# How to start activity from mail default application by link (Android)

Tags: email, android-intent, android-activity, hyperlink

i'm new to Android developing and i'm trying to write an app to send/receive encrypted messages through the default email app.

No problem in sending, since it's easy to send cyphertext email through intents.

I'm finding a lot of difficultes in reception: as far as i know, the email app doesn't broadcast any intent for incoming emails, and there's no way for a developer to access the application's database (right?).
So i thought, as i read in a few topics here, to put a DECRYPT link in the builded encrypted mail that should open my application and decrypt the message. I'm trying to implement it, but i'm confused about a few things.

1) Sending a text/html message with a href tag is supposed to build a link in the body of the email. This thing doesn't work. The link is shown as a plain text.

2) Building an intent and putting in the link as

```
    <a href=intent.toUri()>DECRYPT</a>
```

and then making an intent-filter for my application decrypt activity should work? The intent i sent as link is just broadcasted when the link is clicked?